# Change the way the "caption" animates on this jQuery Image Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, slideshow, caption

I found this great jQuery slideshow: 
http://slidesjs.com/examples/images-with-captions/

However, I'd like it so the "caption" area doesn't disappear and reveal for each image. I'd prefer if it just changes the text depending on the new image.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I achieve this?

For reference, here is the file: **slides.min.jquery.js** ( http://slidesjs.com/examples/images-with-captions/js/slides.min.jquery.js )

And here is a snippet of the JavaScript code being used:

```
animationStart: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:-35
                    },100);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                animationComplete: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationComplete on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                slidesLoaded: function() {
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                }
```

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Tried removing the first caption-animate-part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
animationStart: function(current){
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                animationComplete: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationComplete on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                slidesLoaded: function() {
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                }
```

Worked on the example-page.

|EDIT| 100% working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/byvd9/1/

Answer (score 1):

I made an adjustment to make the caption fade in effect using the opacity that begins with 0 after the image is going to a carreganda - remembering that if you opt for the fade transition effect he produces the caption in the opacity fade but only ensures that the effect is perceived or if you want it to be more atrazado to open the image.

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('#slides').slides({
                preload: true,
                //preloadImage: 'img/banner/carregando.gif',
                play: 5000,
                pause: 2500,
                effect: 'fade',
                fadeEasing: "easeOutQuad",
                fadeSpeed: 850,
                hoverPause: true,
                animationStart: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0,
                        opacity:0
                    },100);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                animationComplete: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0,
                        opacity:1
                    },600);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationComplete on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                slidesLoaded: function() {
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0,
                        opacity:1
                    },600);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```